# Complex numbers, polar and rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers

Express z=(6-2i)(1-3i) in polar form and calculate z^4. Express results in both polar and rectangular form.

Workings: (6-2i)(1-3i)
6-20i-6
0-20i.
z^4=(-20i)(-20i)(-20i)(-20i)
z^4=0+160000i -> Rectangular Form.
Tan theta=y/x
Theta=tan^-1(160000/0)
Theta=0
r=160000
160000(cos0 + i sin0) -> Polar form.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use
$$\tan{(\theta)}=\frac{y}{x}$$
when $x=0$. Instead you need to know that the principal argument of $i$ is
$$\arg{(i)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
You can get this by considering an Argand diagram. Then you have
$$160000i=160000(\cos{(\pi/2)}+i\sin{(\pi/2)})$$

Comment: Thank you and sorry about the formatting